# I have stored all class files in a directory show below but it's showing unable to load main class

Tags: java

```
package neuralnet;

import neuralnet.math.IActivationFunction;
import neuralnet.math.Linear;
import neuralnet.math.RandomNumberGenerator;
import neuralnet.math.Sigmoid;

import java.io.IOException;
public class NeuralNetConsoleTest 
{
    public static void main(String[] args)throws IndexOutOfBoundsException
    {
        RandomNumberGenerator.seed = 0;

        int numberOfInputs = 2;
        int numberOfOutputs = 1;
        int[] numberOfHiddenNeurons = { 3 };
        IActivationFunction[] hiddenAcFnc = { new Sigmoid(1.0) };
        Linear outputAcFnc = new Linear(1.0);
        NeuralNet nn = new NeuralNet(numberOfInputs, numberOfOutputs, numberOfHiddenNeurons, hiddenAcFnc, outputAcFnc);
        double [] neuralInput = { 1.5 , 0.5 };
        double [] neuralOutput;
        nn.setInputs(neuralInput);
        nn.calc();
        neuralOutput = nn.getOutputs();

        neuralInput[0] = 1.0;
        neuralInput[1] = 2.1;

        nn.setInputs(neuralInput);
        nn.calc();
        neuralOutput = nn.getOutputs();

    }
}



    package neuralnet.math;

public interface IActivationFunction
{
    public double calc(double x);

    public enum ActivationFunctionENUM 
    {
        STEP , LINEAR, SIGMOID, HYPERTAN
    }

}
```

this contains javafiles of some classes    **home/prakash/javafiles/neuralnet/math**

this contains javafiles of somemore classes **home/prakash/javafiles/neuralnet**

this contains all the class files of math javafiles **home/prakash/javafiles/neuralnet/class/neuralnet/math**

this contains remaining classfiles **home/prakash/javafiles/neuralnet/class/neuralnet**

now i am currently in this directory how do i run my program which is having main class**home/prakash/javafiles/neuralnet**

Comment: Do you use packages?

Comment: yes i used packages

Comment: Please post the *skeleton* of your code.

Comment: i am new to stackoverflow

Comment: if any mistakes in format please correct

Comment: try `java -cp "/home/prakash/javafiles/neuralnet/class/" neuralnet.NeuralNetConsoleTest`

Comment: Why not use some IDE?

Comment: If you are using command line - please show the entire string.

Comment: @bulbs thanks man it worked